# Testing Click event on relative layout using robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I am using Robotium To test my Android project.In my MainAcivity I have to test click event on Relative Layout.I tried different methods but unable to do that.So please help me what parameters to pass In onClick() method.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The parameters to Click on Button

```
clickOnButton(String) - Method in class com.robotium.solo.Solo
clickOnButton(int) - Method in class com.robotium.solo.Solo
```

Regards

Comment: Could you provide more details